# line 1: [Desktop: command not found on .desktop file

Tags: kde, manjaro, .desktop

When I try to execute this file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Shiginima Launcher
Icon=/home/edoardo/Immagini/SVG/minecraft-1.svg
Exec=java -jar /home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/Shiginima\ Launcher\ SE\ v3.100.jar
Terminal=false
```

with `gtk-launch`, it starts loading and after it crash (without opening).

Furthermore if I execute the .desktop file (the same file) inside a terminal, it return an output  like this:

```
/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/launcher.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/launcher.desktop: line 4: Launcher: command not found
/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/launcher.desktop: line 6: -jar: command not found
```

How can I fix it?

If it can be useful:
[image: my screenfetch]

Comment: Your "furthermore" test is just telling you that .desktop files aren't shell scripts, and can't be executed as such - a more useful test would be whether you can execute `java -jar /home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/Shiginima\ Launcher\ SE\ v3.100.jar` in a terminal

Comment: Although preceding the .desktop file proper with `#!/usr/bin/xdg-open` does work and is quite a fun thing I hadn't thought about until now...

Comment: @Christian I added this line as first line, now no errors on the terminal (no output) but it does not work anyway.

Comment: Did you try just getting rid of the backslashes that escape the spaces?

Comment: with both `java -jar "/home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/Shiginima Launcher SE v3.100.jar"` and `java -jar /home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/Shiginima Launcher SE v3.100.jar` it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments told you, your test is only showing that the .desktop is not a shell script. That's why you get all those errors aswell as why you get the `-jar` command not found since in that test you actually set a variable "exec"="java" afterwards the shell tries to run -jar which it doesn't find.

So first of all try

```
 java -jar /home/edoardo/Scrivania/Giochi/Minecraft/Shiginima\ Launcher\ SE\ v3.100.jar
```

If that doesn't work you might need to look into that first of all.

Also you can set your `Terminal=true` for now, so you actually get an output when you click on the .desktop file so you are able to see what is happening.

Comment: The command in the `Exec` parameter works fine but if I set `Terminal=true` nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XFCE with Linux Mint. But I noticed that when I opened the file Properties of the `.desktop` file... it was saying: "Opening with text editor".. anyway it was fully broken.

So naturally you might want to drag & drop the desktop file to to your terminal to check for more info. But that would **NOT** work. Since you can't execute a `.desktop` file within your terminal. This is why it shows you the  errors you got in your terminal output.

Instead. I check the `application/x-desktop` MIME type in the "Default Applications" app. Which is set to a wrong value.

I opened the `/home/$USER/.config/mimeapps.list` file and manually removed the
`application/x-desktop=` line from this file (under the "[Default Applications]" section).

I also removed the `application/x-desktop=` line under the "[Added Associations]" section.

Finally, I saved the file again.

Then I updated the `mime.cache` by running the command:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Apparently the default application under XFCE at least is "Create launcher on panel"? Which I still find uh.. incorrect.

[image]

Ps. In some cases you might want to try to enable "Run in terminal" at your launcher settings.